# Failed to debug binary - "could not launch process: could not find .debug_line section in binary"

Tags: debugging, go, goland

I am working with GoLand IDE and I have the following simple code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)


func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    elapsed := time.Since(start)
    fmt.Println("elapsed: %s", elapsed)
}
```

When I run it, it works fine and I see the output.
When I put breakpoint in one of the lines I received the following error:

```
GOROOT=/usr/local/go #gosetup  
GOPATH=/root/go #gosetup  
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o /tmp/___go_build_mymain_go -gcflags "all=-N -l" /root/go/src/myproj/mymain.go #gosetup  
/home/myuser/Desktop/GoLand-2018.1.4/plugins/go/lib/dlv/linux/dlv --listen=localhost:35607 --headless=true --api-version=2 --backend=default exec /tmp/___go_build_mymain_go -- #gosetup  
could not launch process: could not find .debug_line section in binary  

Debugger finished with exit code 1
```

I didn't find any information regarding this error.
I read about debugging in Go and it was mentioned to use `-gcflags "all=-N -l"` which is being used.

What can be the reason for this fail?

Comment: update dlv `go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using an outdated version of GoLand, 2018.1.4. Upgrade to 2018.2.2 and the issue will disappear.

Comment: I was running 2018.1.4. After installing 2018.2.2 it now works, thanks.

Comment: what's the diff? i'm using the command line to build with `go build -o _debugbuild -gcflags "-N -l" -v ./src/app/` and when i run it, i get the same error before goland is even opened. previously it would prevent execution until goland attempted to connect

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what happens in your case, but in the original question the problem was that the builtin version of Delve was compiled with an older version of Go and upgrading the IDE allowed delve to be updated to a version compiled with the latest available. Also, depending on which Go version you are using, the command should be ` go build -o binary -gcflags="all=-N -l" -v ./src/app ` in order to make sure that all packages in the binary have the ` -N -l ` flags applied (this is needed from Go 1.10 or newer).